# How to go from type theory to first-order logic lambda-expressions

Tags: types, nlp, nltk, formal-semantics, nltk-book

As can be seen in the [O'Reilly NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book_1ed/), Chapter 10, when I want to model the syntax tree of sentence “Bob loves Alice,” namely

[image]

into first-order logic lambda-expressions, I get the following:

[image]

where on the left I have the tree of types and on the right the tree of λ-expressions. I have chosen to type-raise both Bob and Alice.

My question is the following: from the tree of types I can easily calculate that the type of "loves" must be `<<<e,t>,t>,<e,t>>` but how can I deduce from this that the corresponding λ-expression must be

λR.λx.R(λy.loves(x,y))

Is there some method to obtain the λ-expression of a leave of the syntax tree from its type and from the surrounding λ-expressions?